# How can hibernate can be better over using hibernate template?

Tags: hibernate

I was using Spring framework, and told hibernate template are old and also hibernate-entitymanager is deprecated.
 Additional problem is, Is it important to practice hql ( hibernate query language) to run query? I am little good with sql and session object provide createSQLquery  method to invoke sql query in hibernate session. I am not sure about best approach for database connection. And also need some documentary guidance.

Comment: If not Hibernate template or entity manager then which one you are using? Just curious about it and wanted to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HQL is independent of database.So it is better to use HQL with hibernate.

Comment: hibernate session provide createSqlStatement method which implicitly convert it into hql. Correct me if you know about it.

Comment: Even HQL is converted to SQL at runtime.

Comment: HQL will be converted to DB specific SQL,based on the dialect provided in configuration.

Comment: @Rajesh Native SQL queries created by createSQLQuery are database dependent